# Shadow clipping on iPad

Tags: css, ipad

I have a problem with text-shadow clipping on iPad. As you can see on [this image](http://www.digital-ant.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/2016-11-23_15.47.05_1024.png) the shadow gets clipped. Here is the [link](http://www.digital-ant.com) of the website. I'm guessing the trouble is that the shadow is larger than the line height? I tried to add overflow: visible, but nothing has changed.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Can u add the code here

Comment: the css for the span with shadow is:
`.shadow {
    overflow: visible;
    text-shadow: 0 0 65px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Please add in your stylesheet

```
.shadow {
 text-shadow: 0 0 65px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: hello, that would make my shadow almost invisible though

Comment: thank you, but I'm afraid we misunderstood each other, I would like to keep the shadow distance at 65px without being clipped, using text-shadow: none the shadow would disappear completely

Answer (score 0):

just make it darker on Ipad

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px){
.shadow {
text-shadow: 0 0 65px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
overflow: auto;
}}
```

http://prntscr.com/dd5u5z

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the problem. I added a position: relative and display: inline-block to the shadow class.

```
.shadow { 
   text-shadow: 0 0 65px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
}
```

Thanks to everyone who participated.